# Why is it faster to add to a vector with reserved capacity than to construct a vector from a pair of iterators?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I don't know case 2 faster then case 1  `std::vector<int> vv(us.begin(), us.end())` don't call reserve?   What made the difference?  Thank you

this is code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;


class Timer
{
public:
    Timer()
    {
        start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    }
    chrono::time_point<chrono::steady_clock> start;

    ~Timer()
    {
        cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count() << "ms\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<int> us;
    constexpr int loopCount = 10'000'000;
    for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; ++i)
    {
        us.emplace(i);
    }

    cout << "us creat!" << endl;
    {
        //**case 1**
        Timer t;
        std::vector<int> vv(us.begin(), us.end());
    }

    {
        //**case 2**
        Timer t;
        std::vector<int> vv;
        vv.reserve(us.size());
        for (const auto& item : us)
        {
            vv.emplace_back(std::move(item));
        }
    }

    cout<<"end!";
}
```

Output:

```
us creat!
1028ms
497ms
end!
```

C++17, Release mode, x64

OS : window10 pro

compiler : vc

Comment: Your benchmark is missing some crucial benchmarks (such as compiler flags) but assuming it’s accurate, the reason for the result is probably because the iterator type of `std::unordered_set` is a forward iterator: forward iterators don’t have an efficient implementation for `std::distance`, so the `std::vector` constructor cannot determine the size of elements it would need to reserve for.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
but I test custom class. and it don't call more copy constructor. 
If std::vector<int> vv(us.begin(), us.end()) not call reserve, I predicted that he would call more copy constructor. but it is same

Comment: I cannot reproduce.  What compiler did you use?  What operating system did you use?  What architecture did you use?  What compiler flags did you use?

Comment: Use a proper benchmarking framework instead, because I see many issues with this approach. Mainly, there's nothing hindering the compiler from optimizing any of this away.

Comment: What is the program output? On which machine was it tested? Using what compiler? On which operating system? Using which standard C++ library?  What compiler version, operating system version, standard C++ library version? What compiler options were given? On which machine was it tested? What was the measurement difference between cases? How many times the measurement was repeated? Did it result in the same result difference each time? What is the variance or deviation between measurements? What happens when you invert the order of cases in the code? So many questions.

Comment: https://quick-bench.com/

Comment: This topic is complex and hard. Please take a look on this [CppCon: Chandler Carruth "Tuning C++: Benchmarks, and CPUs, and Compilers! Oh My!"](https://youtu.be/nXaxk27zwlk).

Comment: I add some information. Thank U for the reply!

Comment: Oh I guess
 std::vector<int> vv(us.begin(), us.end()); 
first step is reserve. so  know it size -> use std::distance 
but unordered_set std::distance is O(N) 
it make difference !

Comment: @SuperHong It's not doing an `reserve`. It's unable to assume that calling `std::distance` would be safe to call (not all iterator types can be iterated *twice*, and 
 even far less can do it *efficiently*). So it's literally jumping from iterator to iterator, and resizing the vector whenever the capacity is exceeded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::unordered_set::iterator` is `std::forward_iterator`, but it's not `std::random_access_iterator`.

Only iterators which qualify as `std::forward_iterator` *could* have `std::distance` called for them at all, but only iterators which are additionally `std::random_access_iterator` have a *constant* time (`O(1)`) `std::distance` associated with them. Without the later, only `O(n)` is required.

The constructor of `std::vector` doesn't mandate specializations stronger than `std::input_iterator` - so iterators are required to be compatible with this constructor even if they are *not* `std::forward_iterator`.

What this means, is the the simplest default implementation must assume that `std::distance`  is not even legal to call.

The C++ library implementation may still choose to include `std::distance` as an optimization - but that requires `std::random_access_iterator` to be efficient. Only `std::forward_iterator` would often not actually give a performance benefit, but may be expensive.

---

```
vv.reserve(us.size());
```

This is bypassing the whole iterator trait system, so you can optimize in ways the compiler can't do with pure iterators.

Coincidentally, this whole subject was addressed in `ranges` in C++23, where a range can now consist of iterators not fulfilling the `std::random_access_iterator` trait, but the range as a *whole* still having a constant time `size()` method, making it qualify for optimized reservation regardless.

E.g.

```
std::vector<int> vv(std::from_range, us);
```

now always hits the best possible optimizations implemented in the corresponding C++ library.

Comment: I've just looked into `libstdc++` implementation - it treats forward and random access iterators in the same way: calculate `distance(first, last)` and then do initialization.

Comment: @Evg That's not exactly a smart choice in the implementation then... Because e.g. a `std::list::iterator` is also forward iterator, and with a huge list and a trivial type this can mean literally doubling the computational cost due to the costly pointer chase.

Comment: @Evg aha, but `std::distance` has an optimization for random access iterators.

Comment: @Ext3h -- Re: "not ... a smart choice" -- as opposed to what? If the code doesn't calculate the length at the beginning it will simply insert elements, and increase the size of the vector each time it fills up; all that data shuffling will be far more expensive than a single pass through the input data to calculate the length.

Comment: @RaymondChen That's expected. What bothers me is that double iteration along a forward range could be expensive in general - I would've expected forward iterators be treated like input ones.

Comment: @PeteBecker well, the original question has an example which proves the opposite to be true. If you don't happen to warm up the caches as an ***side effect*** of `std::distance` performance is more likely to degrade instead.

Comment: With a trivially copy able `T`, a target container which is mostly contigous, and ab input container where iteration requires at least one indirection per increment, the only tradeoffs can occur for small collection sizes. At larger sizes, iteration cost often outweighs any gains.

Comment: `std::vector` ctor from range (with `std::from_range` arg) was added in C++23, not C++20.